# How do I create a virtualenv environment in python 3.3 on centos when the main python on the system is 2.6.6?

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv

The administrators will not provide sudo access and already installed pip and virtualenv but they are all based off of the 2.6.6 python they have installed on the main system and will not allow any changes.  I have to do everything by building a virtualenv.  When I build a virtualenv with their python it is only in 2.6.6 and only has 2.6.6 python executable.  I need 3.3 to run my application.  (I cannot install packages with yum either or do anything really writing to main areas that require sudo access)  I tried building a version of python 3.3 in my home directory and then doing the following but then I have problems with missing zlib.

```
virtualenv py3 --python=/home/ted/p3/bin/python3.3 --no-site-packages --verbose
```

Then I tried to install pip separately with the python3.3 but similarly had zlib problems.

Also, I've seen the recommendations to just install zlib from other packages like ...

```
sudo apt-get install dpkg-dev
```

but I don't have access to yum to do that.

Comment: Can you get the administrators to install the dependencies for zlib so you can build python 3 with it?

Comment: [``pyenv``](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv) does not require sudo, and is more suited for managing Python versions than ``virtualenv``.

Answer (score 0):

You absolutely don't need Superuser Privileges to create python virtual env.

1. Download python package from Active-Python Web site.
2. Download latest setuptools-.tar.gz and pip.tar.gz packages.
3. Extract ActivePython Package wherever you want.
4. cd ActivePython, and ./install.sh (enter) you have to enter a new folder path say vpython3
5. Now you got python installed, but its not virtual yet. now place downloaded setuptools.tar.gz and pip.tar.gz into vpython3/bin/

now fallow below: -

```
pwd
/home/hayathms/Softwares/vpython3

cd bin
./python3 virtualenv ../../vpy3
```

Above vpy3 folder has complete virtual enviornment. :)

So activating it is like this.

```
source /home/hayathms/Softwares/vpy3/bin/activate
```

Done!...